# How can i make this center bar on android?

Tags: android, drawable, android-xml

anyone work on iphone must know about center bar in datetime control (like image below). Now i want to make this bar on android in xml, i tried it but it's not same to bar on iphone (the color not like).
How can i make it on android as a xml drawable?
[image]
Thanks for your help.

Comment: you want only bas or full picker control ??

Comment: only bar, i want to make a center bar like on iphone (color, gradient,style,..), but i dont know exactly what color value,gradient of this bar on iphone in order to implement on android.

Answer (score 1):

exists a widget on code.google.com: see [at](http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/)

Comment: thank for your reply, but it not the right answer for my question, i only want to make a center bar not full this widget.

Answer (score 0):

here is the best drawable for center bar i got so far. hope it useful for someone want to make this kind of bar be nicer

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#507E8EAB" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#70333333" /> 
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:left="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:top="0dp" android:bottom="25dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#70E3F7FF" />

    </shape>
</item>
```